# Democratic, not democratic, a valid and useful judging of a community?

Tags: right-view, community

What is the Sublime Buddhas approach in regard of judging a certain community and it's governing?

What makes a community conducting badly?

Which kind of community can only fail (in regard of good deeds, benefical in long terms) by democratic means?

Which kind of community allows democratic ways?

Which kind of community requires authority? ...

Comment: samadhi prajna? it's just on-line, relax

Comment: Without virtue there is no Samadhi, no Panna, no liberation. With wrong view there is wrong virtue. With wrong association, wrong view comes along. Foolish one who relaxes where the root cause comes into play, good householder. On-line does kamma. Nowhere more bad kamma conducted then in the internet realm... "thinking, it's just on-line, where it matters"... wrong view.

Answer (score 4):

Democracy often degenerates into foolish debates.

The Buddha was once asked to help a group of mendicants stop their ongoing harsh debate:

> [MN128:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:4.1): Then the Buddha went up to those mendicants and said,
> [MN128:4.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:4.2): “Enough, mendicants! Stop arguing, quarreling, and disputing.”

Three times the Buddha asked. And three times the Buddha was ignored.

In the morning the Buddha declared:

> [MN128:6.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.1): “When many voices shout at once,
> [MN128:6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.2): no-one thinks that they’re a fool!
> [MN128:6.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.3): While the Saṅgha’s being split,
> [MN128:6.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.4): none thought another to be better.
> [MN128:6.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.5): Dolts pretending to be astute,
> [MN128:6.6](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.6): they talk, their words right out of bounds.
> [MN128:6.7](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.7): They blab at will, their mouths agape,
> [MN128:6.8](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.8): and no-one knows what leads them on.
> [MN128:6.9](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.9): “They abused me, they hit me!
> [MN128:6.10](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.10): They beat me, they robbed me!”
> [MN128:6.11](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.11): For those who bear such a grudge,
> [MN128:6.12](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.12): hatred never ends.
> [MN128:6.13](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.13): “They abused me, they hit me!
> [MN128:6.14](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.14): They beat me, they robbed me!”
> [MN128:6.15](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.15): For those who bear no such grudge,
> [MN128:6.16](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.16): hatred has an end.
> [MN128:6.17](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.17): For never is hatred
> [MN128:6.18](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.18): settled by hate,
> [MN128:6.19](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.19): it’s only settled by love:
> [MN128:6.20](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.20): this is an ancient law.
> [MN128:6.21](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.21): Others don’t understand
> [MN128:6.22](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.22): that here we need to be restrained.
> [MN128:6.23](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.23): But those who do understand this,
> [MN128:6.24](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.24): being clever, settle their conflicts.
> [MN128:6.25](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.25): Breakers of bones and takers of life,
> [MN128:6.26](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.26): thieves of cattle, horses, wealth,
> [MN128:6.27](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.27): those who plunder the nation:
> [MN128:6.28](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.28): even they can come together,
> [MN128:6.29](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.29): so why on earth can’t you?
> [MN128:6.30](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.30): If you find an alert companion,
> [MN128:6.31](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.31): a wise and virtuous friend,
> [MN128:6.32](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.32): then, overcoming all adversities,
> [MN128:6.33](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.33): wander with them, joyful and mindful.
> [MN128:6.34](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.34): If you find no alert companion,
> [MN128:6.35](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.35): no wise and virtuous friend,
> [MN128:6.36](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.36): then, like a king who flees his conquered realm,
> [MN128:6.37](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.37): wander alone like a tusker in the wilds.
> [MN128:6.38](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.38): It’s better to wander alone,
> [MN128:6.39](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.39): there’s no fellowship with fools.
> [MN128:6.40](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.40): Wander alone and do no wrong,
> [MN128:6.41](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato#mn128:6.41): at ease like a tusker in the wilds.”

With that said, the Buddha left. The Buddha left those who would not listen and went on his way to speak with others who would listen.

Sometimes the authority simply leaves and goes on to speak to those who will listen with proper attention.

Comment: The problem with the communists at SC, aside of not fearing to steal, is that they give Vinaya less interest, and so don't understand basic measures... not to speek of not capable to understand a question, since somewhere lost in wrong Samadhi, goid householder.

Comment: And yes, you, they, are already left alone... totally. For one assisting in thieving and often rebuked, continue, there is no use of marxists for a good in this world, so they are left allone with their thiefs.

Comment: If they just would have search engines which find their defiled thinking and errors in their heart. Sure, such they wouldn't be able to develop, not knowing themselves.

Comment: Thank you. Added "thief" to search examples. Those who find it will look deeper.

Comment: Comment as foolish as the answer... Maybe starting to look into Vinaya, to get the base first.

Comment: I'm not sure what impresses me most: the skillful answer or the abundance of links. Great answer!

Comment: @Max, thanks for your kindness. We're working hard to make it easier for folks to read  and find the teachings directly.  The Buddha's teachings are indeed amazing. It is their vastness that can overwhelm us as we slide into the TL;DR world.  Buddhist Stack Exchange is quite an important resource to help us find Dhamma gems together.

Answer (score 1):

All autocracy, democracy, and righteousnessy could be right or wrong depending on the doer's mind moments, wholesome is right, unwholesome is wrong.

However the ordinaries normally often decide right as wrong and wrong as right because of clinging on view (ditthi-upadana), such as thinking about 'what I am answer must be right, others' must be wrong', etc. This always happen because of no virtues/moral (sila),
no 8 jhana (samadhi), and no 8 knowledges(8 vijja) according to  DN1 BrahmajalaSutta, DN 2 SamannaphalaSutta, DN 10 SubhaSutta, and DN 15 MahanidanaSutta.

So, according to DN 2 SamannaphalaSutta, the Buddha taught about virtues/moral (sila),  8 jhana (samadhi), and 8 knowledges(8 vijja) to let the listener understood the way to cease  the argument of teacher and student at the beginning of DN2 and DN1.

To access insight the second to the seventh knowledge, the Buddha taught MN 119 Kāyagatāsatisutta to let the practitioner practice AdhiCittaSkkha (concentration meditation), and taught DN 2 SamannaphalaSutta to start the second to the seventh knowledge.

According to DN 10 SubhaSutta, every 8 vijja is AdhiPannaSikkha base on 4th Mastery Jhana.

To access insight the first knowledge, VipassanaNana, in the smallest particle, smaller than atom, which the ordinary think they are only same one, the Buddha taught DN 22 MahāsatipaṭṭhānaSutta to analysis the molecules of smallest particles (samuha-ghana), time-period of smallest particles' various moments (santatighana), co-working-duties of smallest particles' various duties (kicca-ghana), same time being-knew-objects of  smallest particles' various being knew in same time (arammana-ghana).

According to DN 15 MahanidanaSutta, all above particles (plus nibbana and pannatti) are relative each others as 24 conditions, which means every particle is impermanence, suffering, and uncontrollable.  And
DN 15 is the end of DN 1 which I've quoted above.

All of what I answered above are described follow the the relativity of entire DN's structure. According to the history record, DN was memorized by Ananda-thera, the Buddha's brother. He was the main role in the first Buddhist council who accepted by almost all Budกhist party.

Comment: Good, good Vorapol. Yet, Vinaya before Abhidhamma. It's really not that far yet. What does Vinaya account on it (dhammic right, wrong) was already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Dhamma society is governed by Dhamma; say a Dhamma Dictatorship.

[DN 26](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=main/pts&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin) says the noble duties of a wheel-turning monarch must rely on the Dhamma (nissāya dhammaṁ).

[DN 16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=main/pts&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin) says a Republic also conforms to traditional dhamma (porāṇe dhamme).

The Dhamma itself is always a dictatorship, whether enacted by a ruler or by a community.

Dhamma has no place for the democracy of Mara, where people can vote to make   harmful things legal & acceptable.